# bash base64 producing inconsistent output?

Tags: bash, base64

Can anyone explain this?

```
[vagrant@centos ~]$ echo "10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm" | base64
MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQo=
[vagrant@centos ~]$ echo "MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQ==" | base64 -d
10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm
```

The first string encodes with `o=` at the end, but the encoded string with `==` at the end instead, decodes to the same original string...

GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compare these

```
echo "10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm" | base64 | od -c
echo "MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQ==" | base64 -D | od -c
echo "MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQo=" | base64 -D | od -c
```

If we don't send the newline when using echo the `o` is missing, have a look at this...

```
echo -n "10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm" | base64
```

It's the newline that's being encoded that gives the `o` in `o=`

The `=` is padding and it might not always be there. Have a look here..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding

Different implementations may also use different padding characters. You can see some of the differences here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table

From the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4648.html)

> 3.2.  Padding of Encoded Data
>
> In some circumstances, the use of padding ("=") in base-encoded
>   data    is not required or used.  In the general case, when
>   assumptions about    the size of transported data cannot be made,
>   padding is required to    yield correct decoded data.
>
> Implementations MUST include appropriate pad characters at the end
>   of    encoded data unless the specification referring to this document
>   explicitly states otherwise.
>
> The base64 and base32 alphabets use padding, as described below in 
>   sections 4 and 6, but the base16 alphabet does not need it; see
>   section 8.

Comment: I understand the padding, but where did the lowercase 'o' come from in the first encoded string?

Comment: I edited my comment. I was unable to add the output of `od` due to formatting problems.

Comment: I've updated the answer with why the `o` is there and how you can see it etc.

Comment: I see now that the reason is due to a newline. Echo appends a newline to output, so this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

When you use $echo, a newline is appended to the end of the output. This newline character is part of the base64 encoding. When you change the 'o' to a '=', you're changing the encoding of the newline character. In this case, the character it decodes to is still not a printable character.

In my terminal, decoding the two string yields the same output, but the string ending in "o=" has a newline, and the string ending in "==" does not.

```
$> echo "MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQo=" | base64 -d
10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm
$> echo "MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQ==" | base64 -d
10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm $>
```

Using $echo -n would allow you to pass the string into base64 without the trailing newline. The string without the newline encodes to the string ending in "==".

Answer (score 0):

On Macs, I noticed I had to append "\c" to the end of my string to get it to work, like this:

```
[vagrant@centos ~]$ echo "10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm\c" | base64
```

The result was:

```
MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbVxjCg==
```

Comment: The diagnosis is correct, but `echo \c` is a horrible solution (it is not portable, and thus has unpredictable results). You should use `printf` instead.

Answer (score -2):

PHP also encodes it properly, which leads me to believe there is some issue with the base64 program in bash, as I haven't found any mention of 'o' somehow being used as a padding character.

> php > echo base64_encode("10IXydrdsc4DVAgxzrXldNw5GMeVAHKG:TAO04JuWz4PBVWYm");
>   MTBJWHlkcmRzYzREVkFneHpyWGxkTnc1R01lVkFIS0c6VEFPMDRKdVd6NFBCVldZbQ==

Comment: Add the newline character to the string to see what happens.